# How to determine if custom view is currently visible in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view

I have a `ViewPager` with a few custom views. I want to be able to determine from inside one of the views if it is currently visible or not.

Overriding `onWindowVisibilityChanged` or `onAttachedToWindow` won't work for this purpose since the `ViewPager` will call on those methods while instantiating the custom view from a neighbor and therefor will be called without the view actually being visible to the user.

How can I determine from inside the custom view if it is visible to the user?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I determine from inside the custom view if it is visible to the user?

[View#getGlobalVisibleRect()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getGlobalVisibleRect(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Point)) will return `true` if part of the view is visible at the root level.